# How to change an attribute of a button without invalidating

Tags: validation, shiny, invalidation

I want to change the color of a button in R/Shiny without invalidating it.
Specifically, I want the button to be red if the parameters for the execution changed but only execute if the button is pressed.

I have isolated the parameters in the reactive and only react to the change of the button:

```
# react on button pressed (unfortunately also if color is changed
input$Button
# don't react on parameters changes
paramet <- isolate(input$parameter)
```

In an observer I check the parameters and change the color:

```
if (!modified) {
      # cat(file = stderr(), "\n\ntsne not modified\n\n\n")
      actionButton(name, "apply changes", width = '80%', 
                   style = "color: #fff; background-color: #00b300; border-color: #2e6da4")
    } else {
      # cat(file = stderr(), "\n\ntsne modified\n\n\n")
      actionButton(name, "apply changes", width = '80%', 
                   style = "color: #fff; background-color: #cc0000; border-color: #2e6da4")
    }
```

But somehow this triggers the button.

The only thing I can think of is creating a new reactive that only changed only if the button is pressed. I.e. in my observer I would change a reactive value if the button value is increased, meaning, I will have to store the old value in a project-specific variable. I was hoping that there would be an easier way to accomplish this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would use an ```observeEvent``` function to dectect changes in the parameters, and use ```updateActionButton``` to change the color of the button without triggering it. However, it is hard to telle without a reproducible example

Comment: Not clear. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: can you provide complete reproducible example..t will help to understand about exact what you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using shinyjs with `addClass(ButtonName, cssElement)` , `removeClass(ButtonName, cssElement)`, [cssElement = 'red' | 'green'] and in the UI:

```
shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(debug = TRUE),
      inlineCSS(list(.red = "background: red")),
      inlineCSS(list(.green = "background: green")),
...
```

In fact, I was using actionButton and not updateActionButton, which was reinitialziing the actionButton, causing some unwanted side-effects, and updateActionButton doesn't allow changing the color.